# Storing base64_encoded data in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert base64_encoded data in Db, but it says 'Mysql server has gone'. I have taken Blob type for inserting data then also it is not inserting.

Answer (score 0):

set max_allowed_packet to a higher value (your value * x) in the /etc/my.cnf and restart the server and try again

**check before and after restart**

```
MariaDB [your_schema]> show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+---------+
| Variable_name      | Value   |
+--------------------+---------+
| max_allowed_packet | 1048576 |
+--------------------+---------+
```